# Checkbutton tkinter de python, problema de funcionamiento

Tags: python, excel

Buenas noches estimada comunidad hispana, estoy desarrollando una aplicación para mi escuela, donde tengo que realizar  un inventario con conexión a Excel, estoy haciéndolo en python utilizando Tkinter y checkbuttons, el problema es que no manda la información de los checkbuttons a Excel, el nombre y el numero de cuenta si, el resto no lo manda, a su vez, la parte de modificaCodigo, solo borra los datos. Ayudenme papus , estoy usando las librerias de pandas y tkinter :C
(Es mi primera vez posteando aqui)

```html
root = Tk()
root.title("Control Escolar")
root.resizable(0,0)
miFrame = Frame(root, width=1000, height=700)
miFrame.pack()

nombre1, cuenta1, checkboxes = [], [], []

cuadroArchivo = Entry(miFrame) 
cuadroArchivo.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=3)

cuadroNombre = Entry(miFrame)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=3)
cuadroNombre.config(background="green", fg="black", justify="left")

cuadroCuenta = Entry(miFrame)
cuadroCuenta.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=3)
cuadroCuenta.config(background="goldenrod", fg="black", justify="left")

def agregaDatos():
    global nombre1, cuenta1, checkboxes
    nombre1.append(cuadroNombre.get())
    cuenta1.append(cuadroCuenta.get())
    seleccionados = [checkbox.get() for checkbox in checkboxes]
    checkboxes_values = ["Tiene" if checkbox.get() else "No tiene" for checkbox in checkboxes]
    print(seleccionados)
    print(checkboxes_values)

    cuadroNombre.delete(0, END)
    cuadroCuenta.delete(0, END)
    cuadroArchivo.delete(0, END)
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        checkbox.set(0)

def guardarDatos():
    global nombre1, cuenta1, checkboxes, labels
    
    nombre_alumno = cuadroNombre.get()
    num_cuenta = cuadroCuenta.get()
    
    datos = {'Nombre': nombre1, 'Num.cuenta': cuenta1}
    for i, checkbox in enumerate(checkboxes):
        datos[labels[i]] = "Tiene" if checkbox.get() else "No tiene"
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
    df.to_excel(str(cuadroArchivo.get() + ".xlsx"), index=False)
    
    cuadroArchivo.delete(0, END)
    cuadroNombre.delete(0, END)
    cuadroCuenta.delete(0, END)
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        checkbox.set(0)
        
def modificarDatos():
    archivo = cuadroArchivo.get() + ".xlsx"
    nombre_alumno = cuadroNombre.get()
    num_cuenta = cuadroCuenta.get()
    datos_modificados = {}
    
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(archivo)
        fila = df[(df['Nombre'] == nombre_alumno) & (df['Num.cuenta'] == num_cuenta)].index[0]
        
        for i, label_text in enumerate(labels):
            checkbox_value = checkboxes[i].get()
            datos_modificados[label_text] = "Tiene" if checkbox_value else "No tiene"
            df.loc[fila, label_text] = datos_modificados[label_text]
        
        df.to_excel(archivo, index=False)
        
        cuadroArchivo.delete(0, END)
        cuadroNombre.delete(0, END)
        cuadroCuenta.delete(0, END)
        for checkbox in checkboxes:
            checkbox.set(0)
        
        print("Datos modificados correctamente")
        
    except IndexError:
        print("No se encontraron datos para modificar")

labels = [
    "ACTA DE NACIMIENTO",
    "CERTIFICADO DE SECUNDARIA",
    "CERTIFICADO DE BACHILLERATO",
    "DICTAMEN Y NOTIFICACION",
    "HISTORIA ACADEMICA OFICIAL",
    "OFICIO CAMBIO DE No. CUENTA",
    "OTRO"
]

for _ in range(len(labels)):
    var = IntVar()
    checkboxes.append(var)

labelArchivo = Label(miFrame, text="NOMBRE ARCHIVO")
labelArchivo.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=10)

labelNoCuenta = Label(miFrame, text="No. CUENTA")
labelNoCuenta.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=10)

labelNombre = Label(miFrame, text="NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO")
labelNombre.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=10)

for i, label_text in enumerate(labels):
    checkbox = Checkbutton(
        miFrame,
        text=label_text,
        variable=checkboxes[i],
        onvalue=1,
        offvalue=0
    )
    checkbox.grid(row=i+4, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=10)

cuadroArchivo = Entry(miFrame) 
cuadroArchivo.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=3)

cuadroNombre = Entry(miFrame)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=3)
cuadroNombre.config(background="green", fg="black", justify="left")

cuadroCuenta = Entry(miFrame)
cuadroCuenta.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=3)
cuadroCuenta.config(background="goldenrod", fg="black", justify="left")

agregar = Button(miFrame, text="AGREGAR", bg="goldenrod", command=agregaDatos)
agregar.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)

guardar = Button(miFrame, text="GUARDAR", bg="goldenrod", command=guardarDatos)
guardar.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)

modificar = Button(miFrame, text="MODIFICAR", bg="goldenrod", command=modificarDatos)
modificar.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```